# Cannot add variables to gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

rencently i try to add some variable to gitlab ci variables but it can't. and i got some replies.

when i click add like below(just the original green add buttom in the add variable modal)
[image: addModal]

variables not added. i went to check devtools and i got these replies below:

[image: chromeConsoleReply]

[image: chromeNetworkReply]

- console:

  PATCH https://git.twt.edu.cn/yiban/theory/-/variables net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
- request payload:

  {
  "variables_attributes":[
  {
  "variable_type":"env_var",
  "key":"var1",
  "secret_value":"1",
  "masked":"false",
  "environment_scope":"*",
  "protected":"false"
  }
  ]
  }

and have no response.

my gtilab env info is:

```
System information
System:     
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.7.2p137
Gem Version:    3.1.4
Bundler Version:2.1.4
Rake Version:   13.0.3
Redis Version:  6.0.14
Git Version:    2.32.0
Sidekiq Version:5.2.9
Go Version: unknown

GitLab information
Version:    14.0.3
Revision:   f53d20d4fc9
Directory:  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter: PostgreSQL
DB Version: 12.6
URL:        https://git.twt.edu.cn
HTTP Clone URL: https://git.twt.edu.cn/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@git.twt.edu.cn:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP: yes
Using Omniauth: yes
Omniauth Providers: 

GitLab Shell
Version:    13.19.0
Repository storage paths:
- default:  /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
GitLab Shell path:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell
Git:        /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

What did i miss?

Comment: Running GitLab on Chrome I was not even able to expand the variables in order to add it. When I opened it in Firefox worked perfectly. For sure there is some library behind the code which runs in specific version/browser